# Angularjs and Nodejs validation library, using same rules.json file

Tags: angularjs, node.js, validation

I want to use validation with Angularjs and Nodejs (with expressjs), i am looking for a validation library which will allow me to reuse the rules of validation. I want to keep my validation rules in a json file and want to use at both client and server side. Is any option available?